# elements in my page are not refreshing fast enough

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Good Morning!!

I have a page, which displays data from mysql table. The process is as follows:

The page basically displays one record at a time with Prev and Next buttons that allows the user to go forwards and backwards.

1. The user edits/updates fields.
2. User clicks the Update button, a php script runs an update query. (jquery `$.post` is used)
3. Then another `$.post` is run to retrieve the saved data from the table and it is JSONed to update the elements where the data is displayed on the webpage.

All this is working fine and the tables are updated correctly. HOWEVER, the issue I am having is that the elements sometimes do not show the updated values.
If I go to the Next record and then click Prev, I see the new values!

I have tried adding a delay of 2 seconds but sometimes that also does not work.

Can anyone help?

```
    function on_click3(){   //update answer desc
var modal_confirm=document.getElementById('popup5');
modal_confirm.style.display="block";
yesno5.onclick=function(){
    var x1=$("#cur_value").text();
    $.post("../php/post_text_answer_update_query.php",{ ll_val:x1, ss_q:ad.value});
    var xsender="4";
    $.post("../php/get_after_edit.php",{ ll_val:x1, sender1:xsender},function(data)
    {
        pdata=JSON.parse(data);
        $("#ades").text(pdata);
        xmodal_on();
        nextt();
        prevv();
        xmodal_off();    
    });

    $("#popup4").remove(); 
    $("#popup5").remove(); 
    }
yesno6.onclick=function(){
    $("#popup5").remove();
    $("#popup4").remove(); 
}
```

}

Comment: The delay won't work since $.post is asynchronous request and your data are retrieved when they are sent from the server. You must show us some code to see what is not working

Comment: here is the code. the first .post runs an update query and the second post retrieves the new values

Comment: @leli.1337 i have added code